# HVAC System Just Installed Yesterday and AC condenser outside is blowing cold ir

Tags: hvac

HI my just installed ac condenser is blowing cold air out side .  when I put my hand over it and move it around most of the air is hot but a portion of it is cold. Is this right ?

Comment: What's the outdoor ambient air temperature?  How long has the unit been running? Is the system cooling down the house? What is the make and model of the unit?

Comment: Is it blowing *cold* cold air, or just not-heated air? Does the inside unit cool properly?

Answer (score 1):

Very generally speaking, provided the outside air temperature is 80F or warmer, correctly operating modern residential split systems should have a condenser temperature split of 15-20 degrees F.  If you measure the temperature of the air leaving the top of the condenser with a thermometer, it should be 15-20 degrees F warmer than the temperature of the air entering the sides of the condenser.

Very far outside this temperature range usually indicates a problem.

Answer (score 0):

It stands to reason that not every bit of the air drawn through the unit passes through the radiators. Some will be drawn around them and through other areas. Also, the downstream end of the radiators will have less heat to give up.

Unless an entire side of the airflow is cool, I wouldn't be concerned.